# Bluetooth HSP/HFP not working but A2DP is

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom, a2dp, bluetooth-speaker

I have a Broadcom internal bluetooth adapter.  It is model `BCM20702A0`  (`Vendor=0a5c ProdID=21e1 Rev=01.12`)  I am able to get the A2DP function to operate but not the HSP/HFP mode.  I have tried different firmware and also different configs under `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf` but have had no luck. Does anyone have any idea what I can do?  I have searched and searched google and tried various things going on two hours.  Thought I would give you gurus a try. Below are my system details, please let me know if you need anything else.

```
dylan@laptop:~$ uname -a
Linux laptop 3.19.0-20-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 29 10:10:47 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


dylan@laptop:~$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    4.179038] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    4.179051] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.179054] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.179056] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.179060] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.501272] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.501275] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.501281] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.508181] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.508188] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.508193] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

USB-DEVICES...
T:  Bus=04 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=05 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0a5c ProdID=21e1 Rev=01.12
S:  Manufacturer=Broadcom Corp
S:  Product=BCM20702A0
S:  SerialNumber=083E8E9B280C
C:  #Ifs= 4 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 2 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
I:  If#= 3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=fe(app. ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)


dylan@laptop:~$ dkms status; uname -a
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 3.19.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxhost, 4.3.28, 3.19.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxhost, 4.3.28, 3.19.0-18-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxhost, 4.3.28, 3.19.0-20-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxhost, 4.3.28, 3.19.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed
Linux laptop 3.19.0-21-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jun 14 18:31:11 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


dylan@laptop:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep firmware
[    4.085160] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[    4.085171] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.085175] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.085176] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.085181] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.109764] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e1.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.109773] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e1.hcd not found
[    5.332794] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.332797] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.332803] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.346411] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.346419] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.346425] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    4.109764] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e1.hcd failed with error -2
```

Comment: It might be missing firmware, check `dmesg | grep -i firmware`

Comment: @Jeremy31 This is the output... I have tried so many things it may be in an inconsistent state but this is the current output of the command you suggested. `dylan@laptop:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.188628] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
`

Comment: @Pilot6 can you remove `/* Broadcom SoftSailing reporting vendor specific */
 { USB_DEVICE(0x0a5c, 0x21e1) },` from your dkms package so it can be tested?

Comment: @Jeremy31 From which dkms package?

Comment: @Pilot6 The bluetooth test one.  It seems Marcel missed one with [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=6331c686e664909988ecc35b040e1e96c137f5e0)

Comment: @Jeremy31 I made the package "btusb-for-jeremy31-dkms". It will be available after build.

Comment: @Jeremy31 https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-for-jeremy31-dkms_0.1_all.deb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try this:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/owropuric6iz898/BCM20702A0-05ac-21e1.hcd
sudo cp BCM20702A0-05ac-21e1.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e1.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Then check `dmesg | tail` for any info:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/xu80svavlazttaf/bluetooth-3.19.tar.gz
tar xpvf bluetooth-3.19.tar.gz
cd bluetooth
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

See if it works

You will lose the HSP/HFP after a kernel update. When that happens, you should do:

```
cd bluetooth
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD clean
cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers Module.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$PWD modules
sudo cp btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: I performed these steps exactly as laid out here.  Same results.  A2DP works but HSP/HFP does not work for sound or input.  Any other ideas.?  Here is the output of `dmesg | tail` after following your steps.  `[71906.997877] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[71907.127678] cdc_acm 1-4:1.1: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[72443.660663] usbcore: deregistering interface driver btusb
[72449.568465] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[72464.982373] input: 11:22:33:02:45:EE as /devices/virtual/input/input26
`

Comment: Also after following these steps the output from `dmesg | grep -i firmware ` is still the same.  No change

Comment: Reboot and see if `dmesg | grep Bluetooth` contains something like `Jun 6 11:09:29 braun-X551MA kernel: [149550.832977] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patching hci_ver=06 hci_rev=2000 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=410e
Jun 6 11:09:30 braun-X551MA kernel: [149551.432479] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=222d lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=410e`

Comment: Below is the input and here is the link.  http://pastebin.com/UaV1nsRZ

Comment: [    4.115409] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.115413] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.115415] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.115420] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.444886] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.444890] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.444895] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.457765] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    5.457773] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    5.457778] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

Comment: Anyone have any avenues I can investigate?

Comment: Double check `lsusb` to see if the device is 21e1 like in your usb-devices output or 21e8 that you show in the first sentence of your question

Comment: on 'lsusb' the output comes up '0a5c:21e1'  and it says the same when i issue 'usb-devices' so I messed that up sorry.

Comment: Install updates and see if you get a newer kernel that works.  What is the result of `modinfo btusb | grep -i 0a5c`

Comment: I have updated.  I am on the newest stable kernel.  The output of the above command.  `alias:          usb:v0A5Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp21E1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*`

Comment: Did you modify the source code of btusb or install some dkms file?  I think the second alias output is the reason it doesn't work like it should.  Please post the output of `dkms status; uname -a`  edit your question if the output is long and use a comment to indicate the update

Comment: I have had to install some dkms files to get the broadcom wireless chip to work.  I also had to patch the wireless driver in order to get it to work but I have not modified the source of `btusb` or any other files that I can remember and this is basically a brand new install.    Answer edited to include output of command

Comment: As you can tell I have also installed the same package numerous times in different attempts to get it to work...

Comment: Please file a [bug report](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) before attempting my fix with the kernel you have

Comment: I will file the bug report now.  I also tried your method and it still has the same outcome...  Thanks for the idea though!!!

Comment: Do you still get the same result from `modinfo btusb | grep -i 0a5c`

Comment: `alias:          usb:v0A5Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*` is the output now

Comment: And `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep firmware`  It almost looks as it should work

Comment: edited answer to show output.   Ah there is an error!!! That is almost good news in this case lol

Comment: I might have messed up the name on the firmware file `sudo cp BCM20702A0-05ac-21e1.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20702A0-0a5c-21e1.hcd` reboot and see.  I will edit my answer if it works correctly

Comment: THAT DID IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOU FIXED IT WITH THAT KERNEL PATCH!!!!

Comment: So I have to wait 24 hours to start another bounty.  I will award it to you of course, thank you so much.  Two things I noticed which I will start another question or maybe if its wasy you could advise me where to look.  The audio quality on HSP is very poor.  something that pops out is that under the pulse audio sound check.  HSP is mono sound and A2DP is stereo...  second I have to remove the kernel module and add it using `modprobe -r` and `modprobe`...  I am sure I can figure out the latter

Comment: @Jeremy31 This needs to be sent to Marcel.

Comment: @Dylan HSP/HFP is not  very good quality as it is intended for phone calls and only uses mono and not stereo like A2DP

Comment: See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1859223

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's a bt profile problem with pulseaudio, unless it's something more problematic.

Install and run pavucontrol (`apt-get install pavucontrol`) and go to the last page (configuration) check if bluetooth profile is there and try changing it.

My bt audio conf is default withoyt any changes (ubuntu 14.04) `/etc/bluetooth/audio.conf`

Now, Just tested these steps with a bt-headset (a2dp and hsp capabel) and got it working. Not the best way, but worked.

1. Pair bt-device
2. Check with `pavucontrol` that profile is HSP from configuration page.
3. Start `skype` (I know, but it's easy to test with it)
4. Run `movesink.sh` script
5. Start test call to skype testing service
6. Select recording tab from `pavucontrol` and select "Skype input from" to match your bluetooth device.
7. Speak and see if the volume bar moves.
8. If probles, start call again and run `movesink.sh` during the test call

a) Check bt-device name:

```
pactl list sinks|grep Name
# or
pactl list sinks|grep card:
```

b) Run movesinks.sh with that name

```
./movesink.sh bluez_sink.48_C1_AC_C1_C3_85.hsp
# or
./movesink.sh bluez_sink.48_C1_AC_C1_C3_85
```

And here's the movesink.sh script that I've made. It moves your program sound outputting to your bt device (this does not move mic automatically from integrated to bt-headset):

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Setting default sink to: $1";
# where new pa should output sound for new programs
pacmd set-default-sink $1
# get "active" programs and with while read
pactl list sink-inputs short |cut -f1 | while read line    
do
echo "Moving input: ";
echo $line
#| cut -f2 -d' ';
echo "to sink: $1";
#  move audio to the newly assigned output.
pacmd move-sink-input `echo $line | cut -f2 -d' '` $1

done
```

Hopefully this will verify that your setup works. (I used to have a keybinding, that paired the bt-headset, moved inputs to that and when I used it again, it reverted that setup.)

You should get your main audio back to default with:

```
./movesink.sh alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
# or
./movesink.sh alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0
```

Comment: I installed `pavcontrol` and under the config tab both BT profiles show up.  HSP and A2DP.  When I have it on A2DP sounds works.  But when i change it to HSP the sound stops working and it does not record.   I used my original audio.conf and also your profile as well.  With your profile A2DP does not even work.

Comment: @false The recording might be device order thing.  Try running `pacmd list-sink-inputs` and `pacmd list-sinks` with A2DP, HSP and without bt connected. I can't find my bt-script (don't have the device anymore), but the device could be "state: suspended" or not default (I think I used `pacmd set-default-sink SINKNAME` to change that)

Comment: Here is the output of the above commands. I am not sure what I am looking for in that output so I feel like a noob but perhaps it will shed some light.  http://pastebin.com/g64MpAkn

Comment: @dylan That was the output without bluetooth speaker connected?  Try with it connectected and hsp selected from pavucontrol

Comment: Here are the two paste bins with the output you requested.  With HSP selcted -->  http://pastebin.com/c9sPsyNp   and this is with A2DP selected -->  http://pastebin.com/Qiyds4WR

Comment: Try `pacmd set-default-sink bluez_sink.48_C1_AC_C1_C3_85.hsp` with hsp and see if you have sound then. I'll try to have a better look tomorrow. Also you could try to fiddle in sound settings and in pavucontrol.

Comment: I got roped into helping someone with something but I'll try that tonight. I have tried every setting in pavcontrol... Lol. Awesome thanks, let you know results of that command later

Comment: so i issued `pacmd set-default-sink bluez_sink.48_C1_AC_C1_C3_85.hsp` and now anything with audio wont play.  For example youtube or netflix brings up the player but just wont start playing.  no video no audio noting..  just the blank player.  any ideas?

Comment: Once I change the profile to HSP the sound stops working.  I then proceed with the following steps and run the script using the name of my hsp profile `bluez_sink.48_C1_AC_C1_C3_85.hsp` but it does not work.  Your script runs successful but doesn't have an impact.  This is great as it shows you are trying.  I will award 150 bounty points if we can get this working.  I will even reward some bounty points even if we cant but if you will keep working with me.  I am not going to be lazy, I am going to research so I can understand your script.  I understand scripting just not these commands...

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your bluez_sink ends with `.hsp`. Mine does not change when I move from hsp to a2dp, but your "card: 1 <bluez_card.48_C1_AC_C1_C3_85>" line stays the sami. Try without `.hsp`-suffix.

Comment: Try changing volume from pavucontrol for the HSP device. I think at one point one device needed a "shake" before it started working (auto-sleep or something).